# TypeScript and knockout custom binder

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, data-binding

I would like to create a typescript class that will do all the bindings using the mecanisms of knockout. The first steps are done but now I'm stuck.
I can bind data to my html but I can't manipulate them and make the refresh of the bindings.

So far I have this:

```
import * as ko from "knockout";

module Data {
    export class Binder {
        private _observableContext = ko.observable();

        constructor() { ... }

        public get ObservableContext() {
            return this._observableContext ;
        }
        public set ObservableContext(value: any) {
            this._observableContext = value;
        }

        public bind(elementID: string) {
            ko.applyBindings(this._observableContext, $("#"+elementID));
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it this way:

```
Class MyPage {

    private _binder: Data.Binder;

    public constructor() {

        this._binder.ObservableContext({
            data1: MethodA,
            data2: SomeObject.GetData(),
            ...
        });
        this._binder.bind("someHtmlID");

    }

    public MethodA = () => {
        // do some operations on the binder.ObservableContext() and refresh data
    }

}
```

I tried many ways to make it work but I still can't refresh the bindings after modifying the _binder.
The _binder data is well changed but the results won't appear on screen.

Any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your binder?  Do you simply need to change values of properties inside binder context and expect for UI update? Or at the end it will be something more complex?

Comment: the purpose is to create a custom framework that uses the power of knockout. So the binder object should do all the bindings between my classes (that act like viewmodels in fact) and the HTML, as there is no classic navigation (navigation is done by instanciating classes and loading parts of html in one container)

Comment: If you are trying to build custom SPA based on _knockout_ - it's better to take some _Angular_ instead)))) 

If you still want to do that with _knockout_ - select some good router from existing solutions and adjust it to your needs. I recommend making everyting based on [components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html). So every page could be a separate component and every page can use binding flow, described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50183359/7597651).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will take a look at the components, that's the spirit of my application so it will surely be useful.

Didn't think at first of using Angular. It's not too late to switch to angular, I will have a look too.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what is the purpose of the `binder`, however I assume that your main task is to make TypeScript work with *knockout*.
Since TypeScript is just a super of JavaScript you can do all standard things that described on knockout site.

For more convenient development, however, it's recommended to use [@types/knockout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/knockout)

A classic example of knockout with TypeScript:

Template:

```
<div id="content">
    <div data-bind="text: previousCount"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: count"></div>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: increaseCount">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Your view model.

```
import ko from "knockout";

class MyViewModel {
    // use observable for binding to view
    count: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(0);

    // computed property example
    previousCount: KnockoutComputed<number> = ko.pureComputed(()=> {
        const currentCount = this.count();
        return currentCount - 1;
    });

    constructor() {
        const element = document.getElementById("content");
        ko.applyBindings(this, element);
    }

    increaseCount = ()=> {
        const currentCount = this.count();
        this.count(currentCount + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I will have to change my point of view and do something less complicated than what I had in mind.